# SQL Server Get First That Make Rank?

Tags: sql-server-2008, rank, dense-rank

Edit - restating my need since two guys with way more rank than me misunderstood my question, so I need to make this better...

I have a table like the below. I need to select all of the rows for the first group of 'sec1' rows  where the 'ison' column is 1. So the query should first return the 'bbb' row, but if I set all rows to ison=0 and then make the 'ccc' rows ison=1, then I would get two rows of 'ccc' in the result set.  Can anyone help me with my rank/top? Using MSSQL 2008.

```
create table #grp ( sec1 varchar(4) , sec2 varchar(4) , ison bit )
insert into #grp values ( 'aaa' , '001' , 0 )
insert into #grp values ( 'aaa' , '002' , 0 )
insert into #grp values ( 'bbb' , '001' , 1 )
insert into #grp values ( 'ccc' , '001' , 1 )
insert into #grp values ( 'ccc' , '001' , 1 )

Select * From 
( Select 
    sec1 , 
    sec2 , 
    ison , 
    RANK() Over ( partition by sec1 order by sec1,sec2 ) as rowrank
from #grp
where ison=1
) tmp
where rowrank=1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table #grp ( sec1 varchar(4) , sec2 varchar(4) , ison bit )
insert into #grp values ( 'aaa' , '001' , 0 )
insert into #grp values ( 'aaa' , '002' , 1 )
insert into #grp values ( 'bbb' , '001' , 1 )
insert into #grp values ( 'ccc' , '001' , 1 )
insert into #grp values ( 'ccc' , '001' , 1 )

SELECT  *
  FROM  #grp
 WHERE  sec1 = (
                    Select TOP(1) sec1
                    From 
                        ( Select 
                                sec1 , 
                                sec2 , 
                                ison , 
                                RANK() Over ( partition by sec1 order by sec1,sec2 ) as rowrank
                           from #grp
                          where ison=1
                        ) tmp
                    where rowrank=1
                    Order by sec1, Sec2
                )
```

Comment: If I do this: update #grp set ison=0 ; 
update #grp set ison=1 where sec1='aaa' and then run your select statement I only get one row of aaa, not two. I need help figuring out how to get all of the rows that are in each sec1 group, not just the first row from the first matching sec1 group. Thanks.